# Finding the coordinates of max sum path in matrix

Tags: python, algorithm

I have this method which returns the max sum of the path from top left to bottom right (can move only to the right or bottom).

```py
def max_path(grid):
 
    N = len(grid)
    M = len(grid[0])
 
    sum = [[0 for i in range(M + 1)] for i in range(N + 1)]
 
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        for j in range(1, M + 1):
 
            sum[i][j] = (max(sum[i - 1][j], sum[i][j - 1]) + grid[i - 1][j - 1])
            
    return sum[N][M]
 
 
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
 
print(max_path(matrix))
```

output : 1 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 13

But what I want to get is also the coordinates of the points of the path:
[(0,0) (1,0) (1,1) (1,2)]

Comment: In max_path, you could create a second temporary matrix, similar to `sum`. As you iterate over `grid`, at each cell, instead of storing the max of the cell values to the left or above (which is how you're populating the `sum` matrix right now), instead you store the cell reference (x, y) of either the cell to the left or the cell above, whichever had the greater value. At the end you can navigate backwards from bottom-right to top-left, accumulating the path (in reverse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable sum after the nested-for loops (as written in your code) is

```
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 3, 6],
[0, 4, 8, 13]
```

You can work out the coordinates of the max sum by having a initial "pointer" at the bottom right corner (i=1, j =2, ignoring the zeros), and comparing the values that is on the top (i=0, i=2) and on the left (i=1, j=1). Since 8 is larger than 6, we move the "pointer" to the left, and now i=1, j=1.

4 is larger than 3, so we move the pointer to 4 (i=1, j=0)

1 is larger than 0, so we move the pointer to 1 (i=0, j=0)

A basic (untested) implementation of the algorithm is as follows:

```
def max_path(grid):
 
    N = len(grid)
    M = len(grid[0])
 
    sum = [[0 for i in range(M + 1)] for i in range(N + 1)]
 
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        for j in range(1, M + 1):
 
            sum[i][j] = (max(sum[i - 1][j], sum[i][j - 1]) + grid[i - 1][j - 1])

    j = M
    i = N
  
    path = []
    while i >  0 and j > 0:
      path.append((i-1,j-1))
      if sum[i-1][j] <= sum[i][j-1]:
        j -= 1 
      else:
        i -= 1
      
    path.reverse()
    return sum[N][M],path
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
print(max_path(matrix))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code to get your job done.

```
from itertools import permutations, product

def get_max_sum(table):
    height, width = len(table), len(table[0])

    sum_, *pos = max((sum(table[x][y] for x, y in zip(*pairs)), *zip(*pairs))
               for pairs in product(
                permutations(range(height)),
               ([*range(i, width), *range(i)] for i in range(width))))

    return (sum_, *sorted(pos))

sum_, *pos = get_max_sum(
    [[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 5],
     [4, 9, 16]]
)
```

Output:
20 #maximum sum
(0, 1) (1, 0) (2, 2) #co -ordinates

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it can move only to the right or bottom, not diagonal or left. I forgot to precise that, I just edit it

Comment: @Procardo you have to revise your Prob. Description - not here in *comment*.  It's hard to help - if the req. is changing/unclear at the beginning.

Comment: @PythonBang - it's good use of *permutations* and *product* here. But it could be simplified.  +1